# Are all files of Ubuntu are stored in C drive?

Tags: 16.04

In windows, we was having sites of storing as C,D,E but in Ubuntu, how and where the files are stored?,I am afraid that my Ubuntu files are stored with the main files of Ubuntu in C drive and this will fill the C drive and I can not use it in windows N.B: I have windows alongside with Ubuntu.

Comment: If Ubuntu is using 1 or x partitions depends on the installation -> formatting/partition scheme you might have selected.  Keep in mind that Linux distributions doesn't use drive letters as the Microsoft world is using.

Comment: Don't post the same question twice!

Comment: @Zanna This same user posted this same question earlier. I think it should be a dupe of his/her previous question.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have the concept of drives as Windows does. If you want to get help about your specific situation, please add the output of the following two commands in terminal to your question, without the quotes: 1) "mount" 2) "df -h"

Answer (score 0):

If you ran a default installation, then your files are in:

/home/username/

They should not be anywhere else.